# How to make EditText Clickable on canvas?

Tags: android, android-canvas

i want to place edit text on tap on canvas.
i want to take input from user and set that edit text to canvas.

here is my code:

```
@Override
protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {


    for (Point point : points) {

        LinearLayout lL = new LinearLayout(getContext());

           EditText editTextView = new EditText(getContext()); 

           editTextView.setFocusableInTouchMode(true);
           editTextView.setFocusable(false);
           editTextView.setClickable(true);

           editTextView.setText("sadsdadadadadsadasds");
           editTextView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
           lL.addView(editTextView);
           lL.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);

            lL.measure(canvas.getWidth(), canvas.getHeight());
            lL.layout(0, 0, canvas.getWidth(), canvas.getHeight());

            canvas.drawBitmap(lL.getDrawingCache(),  point.x, point.y, mPaint);
     //   canvas.drawText("(0,0)", point.x, point.y, mPaint);




      //  Log.d(TAG, "Painting: "+point);
    }
}


@Override
public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
    float x = event.getX();
    float y = event.getY();
    InputMethodManager inputMethodManager;
    TextView tv1=new TextView(getContext());
    LinearLayout lL = new LinearLayout(getContext());

    // return super.onTouchEvent(event);
    Point point = new Point();
    point.x = (int) event.getX();
    point.y = (int) event.getY();
    points.add(point);
    invalidate();
    return true;
}
```

Error:

PROBLEM is that EditText is Getting placed on Canvas but not clickble

Comment: It says the null is at line 148 in method onTouch()

Comment: yea i know..how do i fix it?

Comment: better if you dont create new one on touch, provide an edittext in your xml and hide it, and ontouch just show it `et.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE)`

Comment: i got this working but Editext is not clickable...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First dont draw it on canvas, as touches are applied only to that canvas, in your Activity/xml draw the edit text and your custom view (canvas), if still not clickable try to bring edit text to front

```
yourLayout.bringChildToFront(yourEditText);
```

your xml be something like this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <!-- your custom view here -->


    <!-- edittext here -->
    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/settings_text_y"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

This code worked for me. Please let me know it doesn't:

```
final RelativeLayout mainLayout = new RelativeLayout(this);
mainLayout.setLayoutParams(new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,      LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT));
setContentView(mainLayout);
mainLayout.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {

@Override
public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
    if (event.getAction() != MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
        return false;
    }

    EditText editText = new EditText(YourActivity.this);

    // Add whatever you want as size
    int editTextHeight = 70;
    int editTextWidth = 200;

    LayoutParams params = new LayoutParams(editTextWidth, editTextHeight);

    //You could adjust the position
    params.topMargin = (int) (event.getRawY());
    params.leftMargin = (int) (event.getRawX());
    mainLayout.addView(editText, params);
    editText.requestFocus();

    return false;
   }
 });
```